# setAnimation giving an error

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working on **google Map**.There is list of locations with markers on to the google map.

And I want the **functionality** that when some one hove on particular location, marker of that location gets bounce.

Below is the **code** I am using:

```
function google_map(marker_array){

    // Setup the different icons and shadows

    var iconURLPrefix = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/',

        icons = [
                    iconURLPrefix + 'red-dot.png',
                    iconURLPrefix + 'green-dot.png',
                    iconURLPrefix + 'blue-dot.png',
                    iconURLPrefix + 'orange-dot.png',
                    iconURLPrefix + 'purple-dot.png',
                    iconURLPrefix + 'pink-dot.png',      
                    iconURLPrefix + 'yellow-dot.png'
                ],

        iconsLength = icons.length;

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
                zoom: 10,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(-37.92, 151.25),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                mapTypeControl: false,
                streetViewControl: false,
                panControl: false,
                zoomControlOptions: {
                    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM
                }
            }),

        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                maxWidth: 160
            });

    var markers = new Array(),

        iconCounter = 0;

    // Add the markers and infowindows to the map
    for (var i = 0; i < marker_array.length; i++) {

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(marker_array[i].latitude, marker_array[i].longitude),
                        map: map,
                        icon: icons[iconCounter]
                    });

        markers.push(marker);
        var content_info    =   '<div class="siteNotice" id="content">' +
                                '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading"><a href="?page_id=582&store_id='+marker_array[i].id+'">'+marker_array[i].content+'</a></h1>'+
                                '</div>';

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infowindow.setContent(marker_array[i].content);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));

        iconCounter++;

        // We only have a limited number of possible icon colors, so we may have to restart the counter
        if(iconCounter >= iconsLength) {
            iconCounter = 0;
        }
    }

    function autoCenter() {
        //  Create a new viewpoint bound
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        //  Go through each...
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {  
            bounds.extend(markers[i].position);
        }
        //  Fit these bounds to the map
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }

    autoCenter();   

}

google_map(store_details);
```

Above code is working perfectly fine.But when I try to setAnimation,it gives me **error** :

**Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function**

```
$( "#wpsl-stores" ).on( "mouseenter", "li", function() {
    //console.log($( '.lstore' ).data( "store-id" ));
    letsBounce( $(this).find('.lstore').data("store-id"), "start" );
});

$( "#wpsl-stores" ).on( "mouseleave", "li", function() {    
    letsBounce( $(this).find('.lstore').data("store-id"), "stop" );
});


function letsBounce( storeId, status ) {
    var i, len, animation = "";

    if ( status == "start" ) {
        animation = google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE;       
    } else {
        animation = null;   
    }
    /* Find the correct marker to bounce based on the storeId */
    for ( i = 0, len = store_details.length; i < len; i++ ) {

        if ( store_details[i].id == storeId ) {
            marker = store_details[i];
            marker.setAnimation( animation );//In this line
        }
    }   
}
```

`marker.setAnimation( animation );` is culprit and somehow I am not able to solve.

Is there anyone who can help me out from this.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the error.

Comment: That is not complete.  There is no sample data or HTML.

Comment: That is far from minimal.  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the error.  Perhaps by doing that you will find the issue.

Comment: Finally got it worked ! Thanks for your precious time @geocodezip ..